# IIS Default website throws error with .CLR 4.0 System.OutOfMemoryException. 2.0 works fine

Tags: asp.net, out-of-memory

I have a Windows 8.1 machine (2GB RAM + 32-bit OS, x64-based processor) and have configured IIS on it. When I try to launch the **default website** (localhost) which is by default on port 80, it throws the following error:

**Configuration Error**

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file required to service this request. Please review the specific error details below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Exception of type '**System.OutOfMemoryException**' was thrown.
Source Error:
Line 109:

Source File: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config\web.config    Line: 109 
Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.34248

This happens right after the OS installed, updated with Windows Update and IIS configured. Machine is clean and there is no other app, not even an anti-virus installed.

Same this is happening with my other websites as well. Even with a one page 'Hello World' asp.net page.

**What works:**
**When I change the application pool to 2.0, it works fine**.

**So far:**
I have tried resetting permissions C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319
Tried running aspnet_regiis.exe /iru command
Adding features from 'Turn windows features on or off' (Even all of them)

At any point my system has around 800 MB free RAM.

Other Info:
I have a Windows 2012 Server, 2Win 7 machines and 2 windows 8 machines on which my website works fine. This is the last Intel NUC which I'm testing and it's not working. I need to be able to locally host my application on this machine so it can work offline. But as I mentioned, I don't see the issue is with my website since it doesn't work with a single-page website and not even with the default website.

Any help or direction is much appreciated![image: Error message snapshot]

Comment: You were probably near the limit on .NET 2. From my tests .NET 4 uses more than double the amount of RAM just for starting an IIS app pool (230MB vs 100MB).

Comment: Thanks @leppie  I thought so. But I reset the machine last night. Removed pre-installed apps on Win8 and now my RAM is 1.1GB + free all the time. But it still gives that error. Is it still not enough? Does it mean that a machine with 2GB(nothing installed) or 3GB(with basic applications like Office installed) can't run 4.0 on IIS? I doubt (?)

Comment: Having the same problem on Intel Compute Stick with 2 GB RAM and Windows 8.1 (32bit) IIS 8 Express

Comment: I commented out the faulting line and now the default web page loads as expected. However, I don't think that is the answer to your question. I experience other problems after a ASP.NET application has been deployed to the server and suspect that the memory issue may play a significant role in this matter.

Comment: That's encouraging Dan Persson... did you get the exact error or on another assembly? Also, did it work on your NUC once you commented that assembly line in the web.config? I'm also facing it on Intel Compute Stick (same configuration).